# Excel: DateTime Formatting

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

I have downloaded a csv file that has a time field in it. I need to format these to HH:MM (24 hour style) so that I can do calculations. I've tried a few other solutions without success due to the nature that it's not always 4 characters in the cell. Each cell is in "General" format.

```
 825     835     905     907
 927     945    1008    1010
1031    1042    1108    1110
1342    1347    1416    1418
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here, are you trying to go from say "825 minutes" to hh:mm or "825" to "8:25"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To format A cell from 825 to 8:25 or 1031 to 10:30 you can use the following composite formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2), ":", RIGHT(A1,2))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Formatted the cell to HH:MM after and was able to do calculations I needed to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In another cell put this:

```
=--REPLACE(A1,LEN(A1)-1,0,":")
```

Then copy over and down the dataset.

Then format the cells `HH:MM`

[image]

Comment: This also worked, and I appreciate the answer! I admit, I understand Dan's formula, while this one is way over my head. If you have a moment I'd be interested in a break down of the actual formula and what each piece means/does since it converted the text into a time decimal (I think?) which could helpful for others.

Comment: This actually turns the number into a time which is a fraction of a day, so 12:00 would be .5.  It does it by placing the `:` in the correct spot then changing it from a string to a number.  Depending on the formula in which you use the output you will find that Dan's will not work for lookups, because his leaves the time as a string and if you try to look up an actual time and compare it to the string it will not find a match.  His will work for any math functions though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your values start in cell A1, here's a simple formula to convert the numbers into time: 
`=TIME(IF(LEN(A1)=3;LEFT(A1;1);LEFT(A1;2));RIGHT(A1;2);0)`

Copy the formula to a new cell or worksheet, drag it and then change the time format to your liking.